# What happens to running Python script when computer shuts down?

Tags: python, runtime, solver, pulp, interruptions

I've been running a large data set through a code using the PuLP solver in Python. The cdc solver itself has been taking a very long time to solve the MILP minimization problem, but this is expected as the data set is extremely large. I managed to leave my computer on for about the first 12 hours of the running program, however eventually my laptop shut down from a dead battery. To my surprise, when I turned on the computer the Python window was still open and the code was still running. I wanted to know, did the program restart, continue from where it left off, or should I suspect that it's no longer working?

And just to clarify, I know the Python program works correctly- it returns the correct answer for smaller subsets of the large data set (it solves the problem in 16 minutes for 85% of the large data set). I'd appreciate any insight I can get!

Answer (score 2):

Your computer didn't shut down; it hibernated, essentially writing the current state of your memory and CPU to disk. When power was restored, it reinitialized from the stored state rather than booting from scratch.